# AngularJs formatting date

Tags: angularjs

I am not sure what's wrong with my date formatting.

I receive the following error:

Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/ngModel/nonassign?

**profile-edit.html**

```
<input id="birthday" type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="account.birthday | date" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" />
```

Backend Account Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Account extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
....
    @Column(name = "BIRTHDAY")
    private Date birthday;
}
```

The account.birthday field in debugger seems to hold milliseconds in plain string after the account was fetched from backend.

Right from the debugger:

active: true
**birthday: 241912800000**
city: "Essen"
country: "Germany"
created: 1450289294000

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `<input type="date" data-ng-model="from_date">` as HTML code and then parsed it in date in Angular as

```
var var_name = new Date($scope.from_date);
```

Comment: Honestly? For every field i need to convert manually rhe dates? Angularjs api states that is can handle also milliseconds (also as plain string format). There must be a easy way for this...